# Select 2 rows in every category

Tags: mysql

I am having below Query.

This Query is to fetch 2 rows in every industry_id. So if there are 10 unique industry_id means, Query should return 2 rows from each industry_id.

```
SET @a := 0;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            @a :=@a + 1 AS row_count,
            p.*, u.first_name,
            u.designation,
            u.profile_picture,
            i. NAME AS industry,
            l.location
        FROM
            industry i,
            projects p,
            location l,
            user_profile u
        WHERE
            u.uid = p.uid
        AND p.location_id = l.id
        AND i.id = p.industry_id
        AND p.abstract != ''
    ) t
WHERE   row_count <= 2
```

But this query always return 2 rows from only one industry_id.

How to achieve to get 2 rows from each industry_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give it a try:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            IF(i.id = @sameIndustryId, @a :=@a + 1, @a := 1) AS row_count,
            @sameIndustryId := i.id,
            p.*, u.first_name,
            u.designation,
            u.profile_picture,
            i. NAME AS industry,
            l.location
        FROM
            industry i,
            projects p,
            location l,
            user_profile u,
           (SELECT @a := 1, @sameIndustryId := 0 ) var
        WHERE
            u.uid = p.uid
        AND p.location_id = l.id
        AND i.id = p.industry_id
        AND p.abstract != ''
        ORDER BY i.id
    ) t
WHERE   row_count <= 2
```

**Note:** Try to avoid `IMPLICIT` joins. It gets unclear when you are trying to establish relationship among 3 or more tables. Better use `INNER JOIN`. Because it shows better the relationship.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            IF(i.id = @sameIndustryId, @a :=@a + 1, @a := 1) AS row_count,
            @sameIndustryId := i.id,
            p.*, u.first_name,
            u.designation,
            u.profile_picture,
            i. NAME AS industry,
            l.location
        FROM industry i
                INNER JOIN projects p ON i.id = p.industry_id
        INNER JOIN location l ON p.location_id = l.id
        INNER JOIN user_profile u ON u.uid = p.uid
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := 1, @sameIndustryId := 0 ) var
        WHERE p.abstract != ''
        ORDER BY i.id
    ) t
WHERE   row_count <= 2;
```

Comment: I am getting error in this line "(SELECT @a := 1, @sameIndustryId : = 0 ) var"

Comment: Sorry there was a space between `: = `. Please copy the query now. I fixed one more thing.

Comment: Now query return data. I am getting value of row_count is one, even if the same industry_id occurs twice

Comment: Have you copied the query after I fixed one more thing? Please copy now. There's a subtle change I made. You won't see it if you just skim over the query.

Comment: I am trying to use ORDER BY p.id, but it always shows data in descending order with respect to row_count; Do you have an idea to get data in descending order from all the records

Comment: Descending order of what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120345/discussion-between-manimuthupandi-and-1000111).

Comment: there are 4 records in my table; with (Projects table)p.id 1,2,3,4; when i use the given query it gives p.id 1,2 not 4,3

Comment: then use `ORDER BY i.id ASC , p.id DESC`

Comment: Same record I am getting because row_count value is more than 2 for p.id 3,4

Comment: Please share an sql fiddle. I'll get back to you later.

Comment: I have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816115/how-to-change-the-row-count-order