# How to change the row count order

Tags: mysql

I am having the below MySql Query, which is obtained from my previous question.

```
SELECT row_count,id FROM
    (
        SELECT
        IF(i.id = @sameIndustryId, @a :=@a + 1, @a := 1) AS row_count,
            @sameIndustryId := i.id,
            p.*, u.first_name,
            u.designation,
            u.profile_picture,
            i. NAME AS industry,
            l.location
        FROM
            industry i,
            projects p,
            location l,
            user_profile u,
           (SELECT @a := 1, @sameIndustryId := 0 ) var
        WHERE
            u.uid = p.uid
        AND p.location_id = l.id
        AND i.id = p.industry_id
        AND p.abstract != ''
        ORDER BY i.id,p.id desc
    ) t
```

The above query provides below output;

[image]

But I want that row_count in ascending order.How to achieve here

My expected output is like (I just showed industry_id here; row_count is created based on this)

[image]

Comment: I need result like row_count in ascending order,id in descending order

Comment: In your prev question u wanted 2 records from each category. Now I am confused what u r trying to achieve. Where's the where condition and what do u want as output.

Comment: I am still using that condition; to show all the output i just removed here;

Comment: From your answer I want result like row_count in ASC and ID in DESC

Comment: Can u show your expected output based on some sample data? May be there's a gap between u and us regarding your requirement

Comment: Updated my Question with my expected output

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by row_count asc` after t

Comment: When I use this id order also change; I need result like row_count in ascending order and id in descending order